# how to visualize weights and bias in tensorboard when using tf.GradientTape() in TensorFlow 2.3.0

Tags: histogram, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, gradienttape

Using tensorflows tutorial on DCGAN as an example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan?hl=en

To log the loss, the following example was used:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started?hl=en

Using the above as a reference, I added a few lines to view the loss in tensorboard, however couldn't do the same for the generator/discriminator weights and bias.

Code used to view generator/discriminator loss :

```
g_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('g_loss', dtype=tf.float32)
d_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('d_loss', dtype=tf.float32)
```

---

Preparing writer / log directory :

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
train_log_dir = 'logs/' + current_time + '/train'
train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(train_log_dir)
```

---

then for each epoch I pass in gen_loss and disc_loss into g_loss and d_loss respectively, then do the following :

```
 with train_summary_writer.as_default(): 
     tf.summary.scalar('g_loss', g_loss.result(), step=epoch) 
     tf.summary.scalar('d_loss', d_loss.result(), step=epoch)
```

The above allows you to view g_loss and d_loss under the scalars tab in tensorboard.

So how can I do the same for the weights and bias?
I can see that it makes use of tf.GradientTape() to carry out the backpropagation.
When this is used, I presume you do not need to use model.fit() with callbacks,
and instead make use of generator.trainable_variables with tf.summary.histogram(), but I'm unsure how to put it all together.

and you also need to "merge" scalars and histograms at some point if you want to view both?